# Audio won't play in A-Frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, aframe, oculusgo

Im working with A-Frame and when I import audio files they dont play at all. I've tried it on Safari and Chrome and Im using the Oculus Go and in its browser the game is there, but there's also no audio. Any suggestions??

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>VR GAME 1</title>
    <meta name="description" content="VR GAME 1"/>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto%7CRoboto+Mono" media="all"/>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/aframe-gif-shader@0.2.0/dist/aframe-gif-shader.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://rawgit.com/mayognaise/aframe-gif-component/master/dist/aframe-gif-component.min.js"></script>
```

```
<body class="a-body ">
   <a-scene class="fullscreen" inspector="" keyboard-shortcuts="" screenshot="" vr-mode-ui="">


    <!--ASSETS-->
        <a-assets>
           <img id="robot" src="shooterrobot.gif">
           <img id="scared" src="scared.gif">
           <audio id="no" src="no.wav"></audio>
           <audio id="no" src="no.mp3"></audio>
    </a-assets>



    <!--CAMERA-->
    <a-camera camera="" position="0 0 600" rotation="" look-controls="" wasd-    controls="" data-aframe-inspector-original-camera="">
            <a-cursor material="" raycaster="" cursor="" geometry=""></a-cursor>
    </a-camera>


    <!--ANIMATED GIF-->
     <a-entity geometry="primitive:plane" position="+100 -300 0"     material="shader:gif;transparent:true;src:url(scared.gif);" gif="" scale="1000,     1000, 0"></a-entity>


     <!--AUDIO-->
     <a-audio src="no.wav" autoplay="true"></a-audio>
     <audio id="no" src="no.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
     <a-sound src="no" src="no.wav" autoplay="true"></a-sound>
     <a-sound id="no" crossorigin="anonymous" src="no.mp3"></a-sound>


    <!--CONTROLS-->
    <a-entity laser-controls="" daydream-controls="hand:right" gearvr-    controls="hand:right" oculus-touch-controls="hand:right" vive-    controls="hand:right" windows-motion-controls=""></a-entity>



     <a-sky src="1.jpg" rotation="0 0 0"></a-sky>


  </a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors in console? Do you see the files load correctly on the network panel in the browser dev tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect. It should be

```
<a-sound src=“url(no.mp3)”><a-sound>
```

or when referencing a-assets:

```
<a—sound src=“#no”><a-sound>
```

[a-sound docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/primitives/a-sound.html)

Also notice you are asigning same ID to both audio elements in a-assets and a-sound below. Make those ids different